# AngularJS - $watch not working

Tags: angularjs, websocket, stomp, sockjs

**Scenario:** Integrated Stomp with our Angular. On user login, calling a stomp service which sends data and then fetching the same in module controller.

**Stomp Service**

```
var wrappedSocket = {

     init: function(url) {
      stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url));
     },
     connect: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {

      stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
          //$rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $timeout(function () {
        successCallback(frame);
          });
      }, function(error) {
          //$rootScope.$apply(function(){
          $timeout(function () {
        errorCallback(error);
          });
            });
     },
     subscribe : function(destination, callback) {
      stompClient.subscribe(destination, function(message,headers) {
          //$rootScope.$apply(function(){
          $timeout(function () {
          callback(message,headers);
          });
              }); 
     },
     send: function(destination, headers, object) {
      stompClient.send(destination, headers, object);
     }
   }

   return wrappedSocket;
```

**Module Controller**

```
var initializing = false;

    $timeout(function () {
        alert('timeout');
        $scope.$watch(svc.getMessage, function (v) {

                if (initializing) {
                $timeout(function () { initializing = false; });

            } else {
                if (v != '') {

                    console.log(v);
                    $scope.notifications = v;
                    $scope.notification_count = $scope.notifications.length;

                }
                }

        });

        }, 3000);
```

Here svc is an instance of Sockjs `svc.setMessage($scope.messages);`

Eventually changed `$rootScope.$apply(function() {` to `$timeout(function () {` in service. But later figured out in module controller, `$watch` is not working/calling.

**Expected Result** - Stomp message should be fetched inside `$watch`

**Whats happening** - $watch not called leading to no stomp message being displayed.

1. How do I call function inside `$scope.$watch(svc.getMessage,
   function (v)` ?
2. Alternative solution for `$watch` that works every time ?

Comment: *Came to know that using $rootScope.$apply(function() { is not a good practice*: it's actually the proper function to call to make angular aware of a change that happened behind its back. What is svc.getMessage? Why do you start watching after 3 seconds? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?